# Image.getScaledInstance() changes the grayscale level

Tags: java, image, graphics

I have a JTable and need to repaint very frequently each cell, where table's cells illustrate gray-scale images. Usually images need to be scaled for painting to fit painted area. I have two implementations inside JComponent's method `paintComponent(Graphics g)` :

1. Create scaled image `Image.getScaledInstance()`, and then draw it using Graphics.
2. Let Graphics to scale the image "on the fly";

The first method works faster, and requires less CPU. But it changes the colors (gray level) of images. The image below illustrates the issue. First method (wrong colors) on the left, and the second method (true colors) on the right.

**Question:** Why this happens and how to resolve it? Alternatively, any other solution will be much appreciated.

[image]

Note: in this code example I don't actually scale the images, but calling `Image.getScaledInstance()` still changes the image values.

The code:

```
class CellImage extends JComponent {

    final boolean rescale_img;
    final byte value;

    CellImage(boolean flag, byte v) {
        rescale_img = flag;
        value = v;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Rectangle r = g.getClipBounds();
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(r.width, r.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
        byte[] bytes = ((DataBufferByte) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
        Arrays.fill(bytes, value);
        if (rescale_img){
            Image scaled = image.getScaledInstance(r.width, r.height, Image.SCALE_REPLICATE);
            g.drawImage(scaled, 0, 0, null);
        } else {
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        }
    }
}
```

If required, please see below the whole SSCCE:

```
package book_test_paint;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferByte;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.JTableHeader;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

class CellImage extends JComponent {

    final boolean rescale_img;
    final byte value;

    CellImage(boolean flag, byte v) {
        rescale_img = flag;
        value = v;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Rectangle r = g.getClipBounds();
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(r.width, r.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
        byte[] bytes = ((DataBufferByte) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
        Arrays.fill(bytes, value);
        if (rescale_img){
            Image scaled = image.getScaledInstance(r.width, r.height, Image.SCALE_REPLICATE);
            g.drawImage(scaled, 0, 0, null);
        } else {
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        }
    }
}

class CellText extends JComponent {

    final String str;

    CellText(String s){
        str = s;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Rectangle r = g.getClipBounds();
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fill3DRect(0, 0, r.width, r.height, true);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        ((Graphics2D) g).drawString(str, 0.1f * r.width, 0.9f * r.height);
    }
}

class MyTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {

    final int nrows = 17;

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return nrows;
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
        Object obj = null;
        // The value below represents the desired 
        // gray scale of the image in range [0, 255]
        int val = (int)Math.min(255, row * 256.0 / (nrows - 1));
        switch (column) {
            case 0:
                obj = new CellImage(true, (byte)val);
                break;
            case 1:
                obj = new CellText("" + val);
                break;
            case 2:
                obj = new CellImage(false, (byte)val);
                break;
        }
        return obj;
    }
}

public class Image_Scaling extends JTable {

    public Image_Scaling(JPanel panel) {
        setModel(new MyTableModel());
        setRowHeight(25);
        getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(200);
        getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(40);
        getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(200);
        JTableHeader header = getTableHeader();
        header.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setHeaderValue("with getScaledInstance()");
        header.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setHeaderValue("gray");
        header.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setHeaderValue("without getScaledInstance()");
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(header, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel.add(this, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    @Override
    public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {
        return (Component) dataModel.getValueAt(row, column);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        final Image_Scaling table = new Image_Scaling(panel);

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: TableModel is not a good container for storing components, instead you should store the image (at most) and devise a TableCellRenderer. If you find yourself extending JTable to provide curator rendering solutions your probably suffering for a bad design. Constantly filling the value array in the paint method is a costly operation, instead, you should have a simple cached buffer which you update as required and then, based on your needs, generate the value array dynamically on demand (when you actually need it)

Comment: @MadProgrammer, thank you for your comment even though it doesn't solve the grayscale issue. But thanks to it I realized that this code builds a new cell object per each repaint().